# Faster and better way to copy online database to sqilte data base when the have the same model

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms

I Have 2 Database one online and the other one is in my phone sqile:

I looking for a better and faster way to copy my online database to my local database. The two database base have the same Model "MyWords".

Here is my way to copy :

```
List<MyWords> WordUserList =  await wordmanager.GetWordAsync(UserConnected.Id);
            WordSList.ItemsSource = WordUserList;

            foreach(MyWords w in WordUserList)
            {
                mywordsdatabase.AddWord(w);

            }
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: http://www.symmetricds.org/

Comment: @mjwills do you have an example please?

Comment: Curious - why this is tagged as Cosmos DB? Seems like sqlite specifically.

Comment: What type is `mywordsdatabase`?

Comment: @G.hakim it si a sqlite database

Comment: Do you mean its a sqlite connection?

Comment: yes i use sqlite connection

Answer (score 0):

You consider to upload database firstly, then copy this database from local to Phone sqlite? If you can accept this, I think you can take a look the following article, please see Step 4: Copy the database file from the application bundle to the mobile device.

https://medium.com/@patibrijesh/how-to-use-sqlite-in-a-xamarin-forms-app-2c6ec5894510